# Good practices for app configuration storage?

Tags: configuration, distributed

We have a number of loosely coupled apps, some in PHP and some in Python.

It would be beneficial to have some centralized place where they could get both global and app-specific configuration information.

Something like, for Python:

`conf=config_server.get_params(url='http://config_server/get/My_app/all', auth=my_auth_data)`

and then ideally use parameters as potentially nested attributes, eg. `conf.APP.URL`, `conf.GLOBAL.MAX_SALES`

I was considering making my own config server app, but wasn't sure, **what would be the pros and cons of such approach** vs. eg. storing config in centralized database or any other multiple-site accessible mode.

Also, if I perhaps was **missing some readily available tool** with good support, which could do this (I had a look at Puppet and Ansible, but they seemed to be very evolved tools for doing so much more than this. I also looked at software recommnedation SE for this, but they have a number of such question unanswered already).

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be a good idea for your configuration mechanism *not* to be hard-coded to obtain configuration data via a particular technology (such as file, web server or database), but rather be able to obtain configuration data from any of several different technologies. I illustrate this with the following pseudo-code examples:

```
cfg = getConfig("file.cfg");                          # from a file
cfg = getConfig("file#file.cfg");                     # also from a file
cfg = getConfig("url#http://config_server/file.cfg"); # from the specified URL
cfg = getConfig("exec#getConfigFromDB.py");           # from stdout of command
```

The parameter passed to `getConfig()` might be obtained from, say, a command-line option. The `"exec#..."` format is a flexible mechanism, but carries the potential danger of somebody specifying a malicious command to execute, for example, `"exec#rm -rf /"`.

This approach means you can experiment with whatever you consider to be an ideal source-of-configuration-data technology and later, if you discover that technology to be inappropriate, it will be trivial to discard it and use a different source-of-configuration-data technology instead. Indeed, the decision for which source-of-configuration-data technology to use might vary from one use case/user to another.

I developed a C++ and Java configuration file parser (sorry, no Python or PHP implementations) called [Config4*](http://www.config4star.org/). If you look at chapters 2 (overview of syntax) and 3 (overview of API) of the [*Config4* Getting Started Guide*](http://www.config4star.org/download/manuals/config4star-practical-usage-guide.pdf), you will notice that it supports the kind of flexible approach I discuss in this answer (the `"url#...` format is not supported, but `"exec#curl -sS ..."` provides the same functionality). 99 percent of the time, I end up using configuration files, but I find it comforting to know that my applications can trivially switch to using a different-source-of-configuration-data technology whenever the need might arise.